# How do these overloaded operators apply to the expression d***b?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was trying to understand operator overloading more in depth, so i played with this bit of code.
if I understand correctly when i overload an operator outside the class, it's called a global operator, and thus i can put each of the objects in prefix or post-fix form, in this case i used Double(my class) and double.

This code works fine, im struggling to figure out why. specifically in the main function. d***b
how come d*b is same as d*******b?

```
 friend std :: ostream& operator<<(std :: ostream& out, const Double& d);
 friend std :: istream& operator>>(std :: istream& in, Double& d);

 Double const& operator*() const { return *this; }
 friend double my_pow(double,Double);
};

double my_pow(double x ,Double i) {
 return pow(x,i._p);
}
double operator*(double a, Double const& b) {
 return my_pow(a,b);
}

std :: ostream& operator<<(std :: ostream& out, const Double& d) { return out<<d._p; }
std :: istream& operator>>(std :: istream& in, Double& d) { return in>>d._p; }

int main()
{
    Double d(10);
    Double b(2);
    double a = d***b;
}
```

Comment: Dissect your call using parens. Also stepping through the code using the debugger might help to understand what actually happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write

```
d***b
```

C++ interprets it as

```
d*(*(*b))
```

Given this, let's see which operators get called. When C++ sees

```
*b
```

it will look either for

- a member function named `operator*` with no arguments, or
- a free function named `operator*` with one argument.

Based on this, which overload gets called? What does `*b` evaluate to?

Next, when C++ sees something of the form

```
a * b
```

it will look for

- a member function in the class of which `a` is a type named `operator*` with a single argument, or
- a free function named `operator*` taking two arguments.

Based on that, which function gets called?

Hope this helps!